# Get last record by date time based on multiple columns

Tags: postgresql

Wondering how to do something in postgresql  I have a table that has

```
AcctNo    EntryDate        EntryTime   Form    FormSeq   anscode   answer
123456    8/14/20           07:05      ORREC    0001      ans1      1245
123456    8/13/20           07:07      ORREC    0001      ans1      1235
123456    8/14/20           07:04      ORREC    0001      ans2      test
123456    8/14/20           07:05      ORREC    0001      ans2      testing
123456    8/15/20           12:15      ORREC    0002      ans1      1520
123456    8/15/20           12:17      ORREC    0002      ans1      1522
```

What I need to is to the get last entry for each form/formseq/anscode based on date and time

So the three results I would get are

```
AcctNo    EntryDate       EntryTime   Form    FormSeq   anscode   answer
123456    8/14/20          07:05      ORREC    0001      ans1      1245
123456    8/14/20          07:05      ORREC    0001      ans2      testing
123456    8/15/20          12:17      ORREC    0002      ans1      1522

select AcctNo,EntryDate,EntryTime,Form,FormSeq,anscode,answer 
from TableName 
where       
Group By AcctNo,Form,FormSeq,Anscode
```

Comment: You can use window function approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete example below. It does not quite match your data output. But it does match this 'get last entry for each form/formseq/anscode based on date and time'. So it returns the last entry for each date. If you want the last entry period for each form/formseq/anscode that is a different query.

```
CREATE TABLE public.test_table (
    acctno integer,
    entrydate date,
    entrytime time without time zone,
    form character varying,
    formseq character varying,
    anscode character varying,
    answer character varying
);

COPY public.test_table (acctno, entrydate, entrytime, form, formseq, anscode, answer) FROM stdin;
123456  2020-08-14      07:05:00        ORREC   0001    ans1    1245
123456  2020-08-13      07:07:00        ORREC   0001    ans1    1235
123456  2020-08-14      07:04:00        ORREC   0001    ans2    test
123456  2020-08-14      07:05:00        ORREC   0001    ans2    testing
123456  2020-08-15      12:15:00        ORREC   0002    ans1    1520
123456  2020-08-15      12:17:00        ORREC   0002    ans1    1522
\.

SELECT
     distinct on(entrydate, form, formSeq, anscode)  acctno,entrydate,entrytime,form,formSeq,anscode,answer
from
    test_table
WHERE
   acctNo = 123456
ORDER BY
     entrydate , form, formseq, anscode, entrytime desc;

 acctno | entrydate  | entrytime | form  | formseq | anscode | answer  
--------+------------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+---------
 123456 | 2020-08-13 | 07:07:00  | ORREC | 0001    | ans1    | 1235
 123456 | 2020-08-14 | 07:05:00  | ORREC | 0001    | ans1    | 1245
 123456 | 2020-08-14 | 07:05:00  | ORREC | 0001    | ans2    | testing
 123456 | 2020-08-15 | 12:17:00  | ORREC | 0002    | ans1    | 1522
```

The second query that outputs like your data example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (form, formseq, anscode)
    acctno,
    entrydate,
    entrytime,
    form,
    formseq,
    anscode,
    answer
FROM
    test_table
ORDER BY
    form,
    formseq,
    anscode,
    entrydate + entrytime DESC;

acctno | entrydate  | entrytime | form  | formseq | anscode | answer  
--------+------------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+---------
 123456 | 2020-08-14 | 07:05:00  | ORREC | 0001    | ans1    | 1245
 123456 | 2020-08-14 | 07:05:00  | ORREC | 0001    | ans2    | testing
 123456 | 2020-08-15 | 12:17:00  | ORREC | 0002    | ans1    | 1522
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Looks close, but I need it by EntryDate and EntryTime (They are two separate columns) and I only need the last entry...

Comment: See updated query. This assumes no NULL values id EntryDate and/or EntryTime.

Comment: Added second example.